# Concatanation of strings and ints in C++. Conversion from ASCII to HEX

Tags: c++, hex, ascii

I've been banging my head against the wall trying lots of different methods for doing this but none of them seem to work correctly.

The commented out lines are the code in C# that i'm trying to re-write in C++.
Any help would be much appreciated.

```
void sendCommand(string command)
{
    //Convert.ToString((8 * startBit) + "4" + command);
    char buffer[50];
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", (8 * startBit));
    motor.printf("sendBuffer: %d\r\n", buffer);
    startBit = 1 - startBit;
    motor.printf("%s%c%s\n\r", buffer, "4", command);
    return;
}

string strAcceleration(int acceleration)
{
    //string accelerationHex = acceleration.ToString("X");
    //accelerationHex = accelerationHex.PadLeft(8,'0');
    char buffer[50];
    sprintf(buffer, "%00000000X", acceleration);
    motor.printf("acc: %s", buffer);
    return buffer;
}

string strSpeed(int speed)
{
/*
    string speedHex = null;
    if (speed == 0) speedHex = "0";
    else if (speed > 0) speedHex = speed.ToString("X");
    else speedHex = 0xFFFFFFFF + speed.ToString("X");

    if(speedHex.Length == 1) speedHex = "0000000" + speedHex;
    if(speedHex.Length == 2) speedHex = "000000" + speedHex;
    if(speedHex.Length == 3) speedHex = "00000" + speedHex;

    return speedHex;

    */
}
```

Thanks

Joe

Comment: this ought to be tagged with `C#` as well

Comment: Can you clarify your C# comment: //Convert.ToString((8 * startBit) + "4" + command); - do you mean Convert.ToString(8 * startBit) + "4" + command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what your C# code does but for the second

```
sprintf(buffer, "%08X", acceleration);
```

doesn't look a million miles away. Similarly for the first

```
std::ostringstream buffer;
buffer << (8 * startBit) <<  "4" << command;
std::string motor = buffer.str();
```

looks like it's close to what you want.

Comment: I would have preferred to do everything using iostreams but since the original software uses printf (even defined as a member function!) then I would keep to the same style and use
sprintf(buffer, "%d4%s", 8*startBit, command);